# Validate Email address using Reg Expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form which contain textbox for email. I am validating email address using reg Expression in javascript.

I used following reg :-

```
var regEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

This reg is validating email address but the issue is if i used email address like abc@gmail.com.com . It not produce error.

Please suggest me any other reg expression which not accept email address for abc@gmail.com.com

Comment: In the future, please use the search feature to look for answers to your question, first. This particular question has been answered often, before.

Comment: @Cerbrus i checked mostly links of this question but all result r accepting this email address (abc@gmail.com.com) that's why i asked this question again .

Comment: Why would `abc@gmail.com.com` be invalid? `name@position.company.com` is a pretty common email pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this works: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]` But your regex won't work with all emails (like ones containing plus signs - that's a valid email). Yours also fails if I wanted to send an email to someone on a subdomain, or someone who is using one of the (now many) TLDs that are more than four characters. Also, gmail.com.com is a perfectly valid domain name.

Do not use Regex to validate an email address. It will not work.

If you *really* want to use regex to validate an email address, you can use [this fully compliant regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) to validate emails. Notice how long it is? Yes, that's why you shouldn't validate email addresses with regex. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/3697679) covers it pretty well.